# flowtype how to get a list of function return values

Tags: redux, flowtype

I want to extract the props `mapStateToProps` is giving me, to add to my ownProps as the list of props the component is getting. This seems pretty usual for me, using react/redux with flow.

I can define my type manually:

```
type StateProps = {
    activeDuration: ?number,
    activeColor: ?number,
    activeAccessories: ?number[],
}

const mapStateToProps = (state): StateProps => ({
    activeDuration: getActiveDuration(state),
    activeColor: getActiveColor(state),
    activeAccessories: getActiveAccessories(state),
});
```

But all these `getX` functions already know their return type. So actually `mapStateToProps` already knows its return type... 
But I can't use:

```
type Props = { defaultProp: boolean } & mapStateToProps;
```

because `mapStateToProps` is the function itself, not the return value.

The question is: how can I get (not set) a type of what a function will return.

Comment: This question is not clear. Are you getting an error that you do not expect? If so, please provide the error text and a code snippet which will allow a reader to reproduce the error.

Comment: no im not getting an error. I cant figure out how to get the type i want to get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a function's return type in flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700904/how-to-get-a-functions-return-type-in-flow)

Answer (score 0):

The following code can extract a return type from a function type:

```
type _ExtractReturn<B, F: (...args: any[]) => B> = B;
type ExtractReturn<F> = _ExtractReturn<*, F>;
```

Let's use this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  activeDuration: getActiveDuration(state),
  activeColor: getActiveColor(state),
  activeAccessories: getActiveAccessories(state),
});

type StateProps = ExtractReturn<typeof mapStateToProps>
```

Here is alternative solution based on [`$ObjMap`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-objmap) instead:

```
type ExtractReturn<F> =
  $PropertyType<$ObjMap<{ x: F }, <R>(f: () => R) => R>, 'x'>
```