# How to get a function's return type in flow?

Tags: flowtype

With this example:

```
const myObj = {
    test: true,
};

type MyType = typeof myObj;

const getValue = (): MyType => {
    return myObj;
};

// how to do this??
type TheReturnType = getValue;

const nextObj: TheReturnType = {
    test: false,
};
```

I'd like to extract the `type` that the function will return, so I can reuse that type. I can think of no way to get it. The above doesn't work. `typeof getValue` will return the function.

Comment: `getValue` returns a type of `MyType`, so can't you just set the type of `nextObj` to `MyType`? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this. There is also no guarantee that a given function will have just a single type. Many functions have different types depending on their input arguments.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Many possible types can be expressed as the union of those types, which is a single type!

Comment: It could, but I'm not sure that'd be super useful in most cases.

Comment: Could you please say exactly what doesn't work about the code you posted. As it stands, your question is unclear because the code "works" inasmuch as Flow accepts it without an error.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I defined `getValue` to return `MyType` so there is only a single type coming back.

Comment: @PeterHall the above doesn't work. `TheReturnType` isn't filled with an actual type body. (I guess it's `any` now?)

Comment: @saadq ofcourse in this case thats possible, but not what I'm aiming at. I'd like to get the return type of whatever external function, without knowing upfront what that type is. (actual use case: redux's mapStateToProps selectors)

Answer (score 9):

Flow has a `$Call` utility type, which can get a function's return type:

```
type TheReturnType = $Call<typeof getValue>
```

However, if your function takes arguments, you need to provide types for those as well:

```
type TimeoutType = $Call<typeof setTimeout, () => void, number>
```

If that seems inconvenient, you can write a `ReturnType` helper that can skip the need for arguments:

```
type ReturnType<F> =
  $PropertyType<$ObjMap<{ x: F }, <R>(f: (...any) => R) => R>, 'x'>
```

Let's use this:

```
type TheReturnType = ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>
```

This `ReturnType` helper basically matches the `ReturnType` helper present in TypeScript.

Comment: Beware that this currently has some problems when used with intersection & union types: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5056